# AngularJS - get element attributes values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jqlite

How do you get an element attribute value?

e.g. 
HTML element:

```
<button data-id="345" ng-click="doStuff($element.target)">Button</button>
```

JS:

```
function doStuff(item){
    angular.element(item)[0].data('id'); // undefined is not a function
}
```

Any suggestions much appreciated, 
JSFIDDLE demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/h3TFy/

Comment: Should be `item.getAttribute('data-id')`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since you are sending the target element to your function, you could do this to get the id:

```
function doStuff(item){
    var id = item.attributes['data-id'].value; // 345
}
```

Comment: Is this `attributes` part of the DOM or is this something AngularJS brings to the table?

Comment: part of the DOM - not angular specific

Comment: But how  is it used in ng-click ?

Comment: if data-id is {{ data }} it return "{{ data }}" instead the value of data :(

Answer (score 18):

You just can use doStuff($event) in your markup and get the data-attribute values
via  currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id")) in angular.
HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <button data-id="345" ng-click="doStuff($event)">Button</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.doStuff = function (item) {
        console.log(item.currentTarget);
        console.log(item.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id"));
    };
});
```

Forked your initial jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mmd1zht/116/

Comment: As far as I know it works on  all current Browsers. All browsers angularJS is running on.

Comment: tested on angluar 6

Answer (score 16):

the `.data()` method is from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/). If you want to use this method you need to include the jQuery library and access the method like this:

```
function doStuff(item) {
  var id = $(item).data('id');
}
```

I also updated your [jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3TFy/1/)

**UPDATE**

with pure angularjs and the jqlite you can achieve the goal like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fXdqj/):

```
function doStuff(item) {
  var id = angular.element(item).data('id');
}
```

You must not access the element with `[]` because then you get the pure DOM element without all the jQuery or jqlite extra methods.

Comment: As per AngularJS documentation,jQLite with the data() is included in the AngulaJS source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element , hence I assumed the API for the `data() method` is the same as jQuery

Comment: you're right and wrong: the `.data()` method is the same, but if you access the element with `[]` then you you get a pure DOM element and loose all extra functionality added by jqlite or jQuery

Comment: Can you get a specific attr with `.data('key')`?

Comment: No, with `.data('key')` you get only attributes starting with `data-` (in you example the value of `data-key="someValue"`, if you want to access other attributes, you must use `.attr('attributeName')`

Comment: ...and this is why custom attribute names should start with 'data-' (best practice).

Comment: This post is old. Now you may have to use `.dataset.attrname` . Use your dev console to see the object returned by `.dataset` .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using dataset property of the element, using with or without jquery it work... i'm not aware of old browser
Note: that when you use dash ('-') sign, you need to use capital case. Eg. `a-b => aB`

```js
function onContentLoad() {
  var item = document.getElementById("id1");
  var x = item.dataset.x;
  var data = item.dataset.myData;

  var resX = document.getElementById("resX");
  var resData = document.getElementById("resData");

  resX.innerText = x;
  resData.innerText = data;

  console.log(x);
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<body onload="onContentLoad()">
  <div id="id1" data-x="a" data-my-data="b"></div>

  Read 'x':
  <label id="resX"></label>
  <br/>Read 'my-data':
  <label id="resData"></label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onContentLoad() {
  var item = document.getElementById("id1");
  var x = item.dataset.x;
  var data = item.dataset.myData;

  var resX = document.getElementById("resX");
  var resData = document.getElementById("resData");

  resX.innerText = x;
  resData.innerText = data;

  console.log(x);
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<body onload="onContentLoad()">
  <div id="id1" data-x="a" data-my-data="b"></div>

  Read 'x':
  <label id="resX"></label>
  <br/>Read 'my-data':
  <label id="resData"></label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="myButton" data-id="345" ng-click="doStuff($element.target)">Button</button>
```

I added class to button to get by querySelector, then get data attribute

```
var myButton = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.myButton' ) );
console.log( myButton.data( 'id' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular2+ following code will help

You can use following syntax to get attribute value from html element

//to retrieve html element

```
const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('name of element'); // example a, h1, p
```

//get attribute value from that element

```
  const attributeValue = element.attributeName // like textContent/href
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery functions

```
<Button id="myPselector" data-id="1234">HI</Button> 
console.log($("#myPselector").attr('data-id'));
```

Comment: with jQuery it would be better `$("#myPselector").data('id')`

Comment: I am not able to get attr value using `$('#datasheet_link').data('href')` but able to get value using '$('#datasheet_link').attr('href')' . Any ideas ?