# How to retrieve the clicked ElementId in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have the following line:

```
<a href="#" id="12345" data-ng-click="ShowId()">
```

and in my controller I have:

```
$scope.ShowId = function(){
     alert('clicked element id in here: 12345');
};
```

How can I access in my controller ShowId function the id of the clicked element, in my case 12345?

Notice the bind is not within the ng-repeat so I can access the item id or something like that.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673418/angularjs-get-element-attributes-values

Comment: Why don't you simply pass data as a parameter? Data-ng-click="ShowId(1234)"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I solved this:

```
<a href="#" id="12345" data-ng-click="ShowId($event)">   

$scope.ShowId = function(event)
{
   alert(event.target.id);
};
```

Comment: it is not working for me, I have added id={{$index+1}} and same function I have writen in JS but `event.target.id` is showing blank in console.
is there any other way ?

Answer (score 5):

```
<button data-id="101" ng-click="showDetail($event)">click Me</button>

$scope.showDetail = function(event)
{
  console.log($(event.target).attr("data-id"));
}
```

Comment: While your answer might be correct, without any explanation it's not especially helpful.