# Add click event to element, but not its children in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this can be done with jQuery as shown here: [How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children)

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;

  alert( 'clicked the foobar' );
});
```

But in angular, `this` keyword is not binded to the element when I use something like:

```
<div ng-dblclick="ctrl.doubleClickHandler($event)">
    parent, event should fire here.
    <div>child, event should not fire here.</div>
</div>
```

and in my controller:

```
this.doubleClickHandler = doubleClickHandler;
function doubleClickHandler(event) {
  console.log(this); // this binds to controller
  console.log(event);
}
```

The event **fires**, but I need to prevent it from firing when I click on the element's children.

I don't want to hardcode a check on the `event.target` based on class or attribute because it might change later. Is there anyway to achieve this within the HTML tag, or in JavaScript without hardcoding the element's class or attributes (similar to the technique of binding the `this` keyword in jQuery)?

Comment: why you used private function in your angular controller?

Comment: @Maher I have `this.doubleClickHandler = doubleClickHandler;` in my controller, but that is besides the point I think?

Comment: @Maher I've been taught to keep any controller logic that does not need to be tied to $scope private within the controller via this.ctrlFunc() rather than $scope.cntrlFunc(). It is still public in that you can call the function within the controller via the name you assign the controller.

Comment: i know that, we can define scopes as anything in controller, but in this sample we define the function as private, so we can't get the console.

Comment: are you using `jquery` along with `angular`?

Comment: @K.Toress yes, I can use jQuery if necessary.

Comment: Possibly related question [AngularJS - get element attributes values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24673418/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can compare `target` and `currentTarget`. The former is the clicked element and the latter is the element with the handler.

```
function doubleClickHandler(event) {
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) return;
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property is helpful.

Comment: great :), simple as that

Comment: Yeah, this is not actually an Angular-specific answer. In Angular, if you also want to handle events from inner non-button elements like `<span>`, you can check if `event.target` has attributes like `[ng-click]`.

Comment: You saved my life with that currentTarget, thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
<div ng-dblclick="ctrl.doubleClickHandler($event) $event.stopPropagation()">
```

reference: [What's the best way to cancel event propagation between nested ng-click calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193539/whats-the-best-way-to-cancel-event-propagation-between-nested-ng-click-calls)

Comment: This does not work. I think it's because the children has that exact same event listener, just firing with different `event.target`. So event fires anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> i update the answer by create directive with jquery in your sample.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
            var ctrl = this;


            ctrl.doubleClickHandler = function () {
                alert("parent clicked")
            }
        });


        app.directive("directiveName", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    click: "&"
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attr) {

                    element.on('click', function (e) {
                        if (e.target !== this) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            scope.click()
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        })
```

```css
.foobar span {
            background: red;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller as ctrl">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div click="ctrl.doubleClickHandler()" directive-name class="foobar">

        parent

        <span>
            child
        </span>

    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, you misunderstood my question, the event is firing, but I need to only fire on the element with `ng-dbclick`, but not its children.

Comment: thanks for the new answer, but it is an overkill, the answer that I accepted is way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If your using `jquery` try this,

```
<div class="foobar"> .foobar (alert)
      <span>child (no alert)</span>
</div>

$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;

    $scope.myFunc(e);
});


$scope.myFunc = function(e) {
     $scope.clicked = "Parent Cicked";
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/nBvlOMtPpXe48lhL2cEV?p=preview)

surely its not leading to a good programmatic skills. Hence you can try below example with `angular` and `JS`

```
<div class="foobar" data-parent="true" ng-click="myFunc($event)"> .foobar (alert)
      <span>child (no alert)</span>
</div>

// add data attribute as data-parent="true"

$scope.myFunc = function(e) {
    if (! e.target.hasAttribute('data-parent'))
        return;

    $scope.clicked = "Parent Cicked";
};

//if clicked element has `data-parent` property do the things.
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3h74Pw5Jsy9lRh7d5Sl7?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would prefer not to check on attributes or classes(see description of question). Otherwise it defeats the purposes of adding `ng-click` on that particular element, since I could just add it on `body` and achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in-line this way (tested & proved):

```html
<div (click)="$event.target==$event.currentTarget ? yourFunctionHere():null">
```

`$event.target==$event.currentTarget` checks whether to run `yourFunctionHere()` or not (being `null` here, if you like you could replace it with another function too).

---

[event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is "The associated [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)."

[event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is "An [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) representing the object to which the current event handler is attached."

Essentially what you are doing is checking whether your current action matches that of the current elements triggered action. If they're the same, then we run your code, if not we run `null` (which does nothing).