# Determining Angular UI modal height programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0IX3A2unpaHJMC1M5brZ?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal with an alert popup that should display the modal height. Instead, it shows an empty variable. Where's the error?

HTML

```
 <div the-modal></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("ctl", function($scope, $compile) {});


app.directive("theModal", function($uibModal, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

        scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: false,
          scope: scope,
          template: 'Some Text',
          appendTo: element
        });

        $timeout(function(){
          alert("Modal height is: " + element.css("height"));
        },500);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `element.css` is used for setting CSS properties to your element, not getting

Comment: so how do I get the height?

Comment: Please try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673418/angularjs-get-element-attributes-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content has been placed inside div with `modal-dialog` class inside directive modal placeholder element. So ideally you should be looking at `element`'s inner `modal-content` class.

```
element[0].querySelector('.modal-dialog').offsetHeight
```